# Server configuration for referral URL

Tags: php, web-services, apache, .htaccess

I have a domain called `example.com` that takes a parameter `?ref=XXXXXX`.

The referral URLs are `ex.co/XXXXXX`

My question is, when a user goes to `ex.co/AhJ7z1` or any random string, how do I configure my server to forward to `example.com/?ref=AhJ7z1`.

Is that something that can be done in `.htaccess` or `php.ini` or something like PHP?

**EDIT :**

I'd like this to be done in a PHP script if possible so that I can reserve certain URLs and restrict URLs outside of what I want.

Is there an `.htaccess` script I could utilize `index.php` in root directory to do this?

Comment: foward like permanent redirect? or hidden redirect (like SEO)?

Comment: Which HTTP server are you using? Apache? NginX? Lighttpd? IIS? Other?

Comment: Basically, anything that comes after ex.co to be redirected to the example.com domain with the ref parameter attached. Using Apache.

Comment: I am using these URLs as referral URLs with shorter domain for easier portability (ie twitter)

Comment: Just thought I'd mention that twitter shortens your url anyways, so twitter users won't even see your short domain name.

Comment: Twitter will even "shorten" a 10 character URL to a 20 character t.co link. Heh.

Comment: Twitter is not its only use. Displaying ex.co/abcdef is much more elgant than example.com/?ref=abcdef.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your .htaccess you can do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ex\.co$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/?ref=$1 [L,R]
```

EDIT: to redirect to index.php

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ex\.co$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?ref=$1 [L]
```

Then it's a matter of you writing your index.php script to grab the 'ref' parameter and find what URL to redirect to.

Comment: I've decided to go with your first suggestion. Although, it doesn't work. There is no response or change with those two lines...

Comment: Nevermind, it's all good. I'm an idiot and forgot `RewriteEngine on`

Comment: my bad, sometimes I forget to include that